# Ubuntu live USB drive not recognized by mac

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, boot-camp, macbook-pro, liveusb

I created a USB drive of Ubuntu 10.4 desktop edition (64-bit) on a 13" macbook pro following the steps from http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download but when I restart the system and press and hold the option key the usb drive does not show up as a bootable drive.

Can somebody explain me how to make the usb show up as a bootable drive dring system startup ?

PS: do I need to install bootcamp ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) for this says it depends very much on what generation Macbook you have. You can find the version by going to Apple Menu->About the Mac->More Info and looking at the `Model Identifier`.

According to the guide, any Macbook Pro beyond Generation 6 won't run because of "an unsupported chipset". But else, the guide above should help. It also says that you'll need to install a bootloader called [rEFit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) and, yes, Boot Camp.

Not being a Mac user, I can't tell you much more, but if it won't boot it's either because your MacBook is too new or you didn't install rEFIt.

Answer (score 0):

Which type of USB are you using?
If it is a Verbatim 'Tuff & Tiny' USB flash drive then it probably is a problem with the drive.